# how to display selected gridview elements text one by one in listview in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview

I have a listview with three coloumns as itemname, quantity, price. Also i have a gridview buttons. Now what i want is 
when the gridview buttons are clicked, that particular items name need to display in coloumn of itemname in listview.

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.R.string;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListviewAdapter listviewAdapter;
    List<Constant> constantlist = new ArrayList<Constant>();

    ListView list;
    String[] item;
    String[] quantity;  
    String[] price;

    //string getprice;
    //String balaji = "shankar";



    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

    GridView grid;

        static final String[] letters = new String[] { 
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};



    //private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, letters);

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //TextView currentLetter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                //currentLetter.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });





        item = new String[] {"Pizza", "Burger", "Biriyani" };   


        quantity = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};


        price = new String[] {"10", "60", "60"};



        for(int i=0;i<item.length;i++){
            Constant constant = new Constant (item[i], quantity[i], price[i]);
            constantlist.add(constant);

        }



        list= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);




        listviewAdapter = new ListviewAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_row, constantlist);

        list.setAdapter(listviewAdapter); 

        }
}
}
```

below is my adapter class

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Constant>{


    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Constant> constantlist;


    public ListviewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<Constant> worldpopulationlist) {
        super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);
        //mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        this.context = context;
        this.constantlist = worldpopulationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView item;
        TextView quantity;
        TextView price;
    }


    public View getView(int position,  View view, ViewGroup parent){
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(view == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

            holder.item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item);
            holder.quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity);
            holder.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);

            view.setTag(holder);        
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

        holder.item.setText(constantlist.get(position).getItem());
        holder.quantity.setText(constantlist.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.price.setText(constantlist.get(position)
                .getPrice());

        return view;

    }

    public List<Constant> getWorldPopulation() {
        return constantlist;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) On Button Click Listener send data (name of Button) to the activity of Listview or if you have made database then add this into database and in ListActivity call it from database.

2) If you have done anything then please put it in question so we can give you more acurate answer.